# TestNG reporting in maven

Tags: jenkins, maven-2, continuous-integration, testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

For a project I use jenkins as CI platform, maven for a build framework, and TestNG for a testing framework (integration between maven and TestNG is through the failsafe plugin).
Jenkins runs scheduled nightly builds, invokes maven which does the actual build and executes the tests through the failsafe plugin. The failsafe plugin  produces and html report which is nice but is just an HTML.

In contrast to jenkins, Team City produces much more detailed reports and provides the ability to track the history of a test- how often does it get broken, etc., suspend tests,... I know TeamCity is paid and well expensive (and in the parallel universe of Microsoft )but still do you know of some plugin/extension that gets Jenkins a bit closer to TC in this respect.
Or do you know how hard it is Jenkins to be extended in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about "a bit closer", this gives a trend over time of your run failures : 
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/testng-plugin

Comment: Yes, is does most of the job. Thank You.